# Strip all VBA code from any office file using C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, ms-word

I want to strip all VBA code from any office document using c# , i was trying to use this code from codeproject :

```
string file = @"D:\AmlanSandbox\MacroRemoval\
    OfficeDocMacroUtility\OfficeDocMacroUtility\FileTank\Jhinku.docm";
object objTypeMissing = Type.Missing;
object filePath = file;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordAppl = 
    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = null;
try
{
     doc = wordAppl.Documents.Open(ref filePath, ref objTypeMissing, 
        ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, 
        ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, 
        ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, 
        ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing, 
        ref objTypeMissing, ref objTypeMissing);
     if (doc.HasVBProject)
     {
       wordAppl.OrganizerDelete(file, "NewMacros", 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOrganizerObject.wdOrganizerObjectProjectItems);
     }
     doc.Close(ref objTypeMissing,ref objTypeMissing,ref objTypeMissing);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    wordAppl = null;
    doc = null;
}
```

but it's not doing the job.
can anyone help ?

Comment: You're closing the document, but you're not *saving* it. You need to save your changes. Try adding a line before doc.Close like: doc.Save(); If that doesn't help, please describe how it's "not doing the job".

Comment: Thank you Cindy it Worked :)

Comment: Thanks for confirming that was the problem. I've posted it in an Answer...

Comment: Thank you for the Help :-)))) i appreciate it.

Comment: You're quite welcome :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the document, but you're not saving it. You need to save your changes. Try adding a line before doc.Close like:

```
doc.Save();
```